# Why the voltage in a circuit changes when the battery has a resistance but not when the battery doesn't has a resistance?

Tags: voltage, resistance, voltmeter

I was learning the basics of electronics with an [interactive simulation of a DC circuit on phet.colorado.edu](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/legacy/circuit-construction-kit-dc) and I notice this weird pattern.

[image]

And also, in real life, with a real battery, what rule applies? Does the voltage between the two sides of a battery also equals the voltage of the battery or does it depends on the resistance on the circuit?

Comment: Google the term "voltage divider"

Comment: The short story is: when the battery is delivering a current I to the load, that same current flows into its internal series resistance. A voltage difference deltaV = Rb * I develops and this is subtracted from the nominal voltage of the battery (i.e. the load will see a voltage lower than nominal). For a given load current, the higher the internal resistance, the higher is the voltage loss. In an ideal battery, there is no internal resistance to lose voltage across, so, the voltage cannot change and is always the nominal one. But that is ideal behavior. Like a politician who does not steal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To first approximation, you can think of a battery as a fixed voltage source with a resistance in series.  Your overall circuit therefore looks like this:

[image: ][1]]

R1 and R2 form a *voltage divider* so that the voltage you see coming out of the battery is less than the battery's internal voltage.

For good batteries properly suited to the application, R1 is "low" compared to the effective load resistance (R2).  The voltage drop is therefore usually small.

In your second example above, R1 is 9 Ω  That's significant when the load is 40 Ω.  In fact, with those two values, the voltage divider will give you (40 Ω)/(9 Ω + 40 Ω) = 82% of the battery's actual internal voltage.

If you just connect a voltmeter to the battery, then R2 is very large, like 10 MΩ, so you won't notice the tiny voltage drop due to R1 being in series.  In fact, this is how you measure the battery's internal voltage (determine V1 in the schematic above).

Batteries are complicated, and in reality things are not this simple.  The biggest gotcha is that V1 also varies with a number of conditions, like temperature, discharge state of the battery, immediate previous history, etc.  But, the above is a useful enough first approximation to explain what you saw.

Answer (score 1):

All real batteries have internal resistance. When they deliver a current, their terminal voltage drops. A battery with no internal resistance is a model, an abstraction, that can be convenient to think about.

Some batteries have such a low internal resistance, that if you draw a modest current, you might not notice any change at all with a normal meter. For instance, drive a few LEDs with a car battery or a LiPo. Drive the same LEDs from a coin cell, and you will see a big change in output voltage.

Car batteries and LiPos do have a finite internal resistance however, if you short circuit them, the current that flows is not infinite, just too big for safety, possibly in the 100s of amps.

Answer (score 0):

## This assumes you understand Ohm's Law

Also you must understand a resistor divider effect on voltage.

We often refer to Voltage sources as ideal with Rs=0 for simplicity, but not even superconductors are perfect. We usually refer to effective series Resistance as ESR under certain assumptions, such as constant temperature.

The best LiPo might have an ESR of 5 mΩ. A dead LiPo cell that can no longer store much charge might have an ESR >100mΩ progressing to >1 Ohm quickly.

The internal heating from current losses causes chemical reactions to create an insulation coating on the electrodes which also contaminates the highly corrosive dielectric (aka electrolyte) to sometimes self-discharge causing more heat and rapid escalation of self-damage.

- A Car battery is rated by its ability to crank an engine with a voltage drop from 12.5 (100%SoC) down to 7.5V . This is called CA or Cranking Amps. It is higher than the so-called Cold Cranking Amp rating, which only occurs on fresh, fully charged batteries at a low temp such as 0'C.

  - This drop is normally linear in uncontaminated 6x2V cell acid is the battery **ESR = 5Vdrop/Imax** for 30 seconds of the 6 cells in series that makeup a flooded cell lead acid in a 12 V battery whose normal float charge range is **11.5 to 12.5V for near 0 to 100% State of Charge (SoC)**.

## Additional Insight

- Similar to batteries, all power supplies drop voltage with rise in current = ESR which is invert to DC load regulation in % of voltage drop. Thus for small ratios like 2% load regulation a good Voltage regulator can withstand a load of 1/(2%) =50x ESR of the regulator.
- Similiar to Power supplies all diodes have a series resistance when saturated, which dominates the small voltage rise with current. We call this incremental or differential resistance also ESR. It is inversely related to Pd max of the device

  - ESR is also inverse to capacitor value in a given type and physical size so C*ESR is constant but proportional to physical size of the cap given the useful metric of T=C*ESR which is related to Dissipation Factor the ratio of impedances for loss/reactance at 120Hz , typically.
  - It also is related to storage capacity variations of a  battery except instead of T in microseconds or milliseconds given a Ampere hours which declines for higher currents.
  - and thus also inverse to mA capacity , size and age of a LiPo cell ....
  - or an alkaline cell or a coin cell which has one of the highest ESR's in kΩ.

The assumption in all these cases is that this behaviour is linear at room temp, but as we know voltage of all these devices has some temperature coefficient usually negative (NTC) except MOSFETs (PTC) . However some with dead car battery experience know about the non-linear characteristics that occur with advanced aging, where a fast turning motor sudden drops and won't resume initial behaviour unless waiting or a short trickle charge to give a sudden short term power surge then due quickly again. Here the battery ESR starts to mimic a semiconductor but not in useful ways, rather sudden death then temporary resurrection.